# How the length in clang-format output-replacement-xml be count

Tags: clang-format

Applying `clang-format` (version 11.0.1 & 16.0.0) with `--output-replacements-xml` gives output as

```
<replacement offset='1388' length='0'> </replacement>
```

When applying `clang-format` to the code I've got one space added.

```
 -    MOCK_METHOD(void, getSha1, (Sha1& sha1), (const, override));
 -    MOCK_METHOD(void, getSha1, (Sha1 & sha1), (const, override));
```

shouldn't the length for `--output-replacement-xml` be `1`?